# MongoDB : combine some collections into one collection with an extra field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB queries and I am facing some problem to perform a basic query.

I have some collections in MongoDB for each month that each document has two fields:

```
myCollection_2017_1
{username:"foo1", credit:"bar1"}

myCollection_2017_2
{username:"foo2", credit:"bar2"}

myCollection_2017_3
{username:"foo3", credit:"bar3"}
.
.
.
```

I want to combine these different months into one bigger collection with an extra field for year/month:

```
myCollection
{username:"foo1", credit:"bar1", date:"20171"}
{username:"foo2", credit:"bar2", date:"20172"}
{username:"foo3", credit:"bar3", date:"20173"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by `map`ing through each of the collection adding `date` attribute to each object. For instance

```
myCollection_2017_1_records = myCollection_2017_1.map(it => {
  return  Object.assign(it, { date: 20171 })
})
```

Then merge the three new arrays like so

```
myCollection = myCollection_2017_1_records
  .concat(myCollection_2017_2_records)
  .concat(myCollection_2017_3_records)
```

EDIT: The above only works if `myCollection_2017_1` is of type Array. In case it is an Object, you could iterate it as follows

```
 myCollection_2017_1_records = Object.keys(myCollection_2017_1).map(key => {
    return  Object.assign(myCollection_2017_1[key], { date: 20171 })
 })
```

Comment: Failed to execute script: Error: TypeError: db.myCollection_2017_1.map is not a function :@(shell):1:31

Comment: How to execute this query? the order or something

Comment: I assumed that db.myCollection_2017_1 is an array containing objects. You can confirm this by running `console.log(typeof db.myCollection_2017_1)`. It could be `Object` in which case you should use a differenct approach to map

Comment: Where to  run `console.log(typeof db.myCollection_2017_1)` ? I am using Robo T3

Comment: You mean Robo 3T? In that case you should do `typeof db.getCollection('myCollection_2017_1').find({})` which returns an object. I have edited the answer to illustrate iteration over Objects as well

Comment: `Failed to execute script.

Error:
ReferenceError: myCollection_2017_1 is not defined :
myCollection_2017_1_records<@(shell):2:5
@(shell):1:31
`

Comment: Robo 3T has a panel on the left that lists available collections. If `myCollection_2017_1` isn't listed there, then you're sure to get that error. Perhaps it would help if you explain what you wish to achieve. Must it necessarily be done on Robo 3T?